# Can i navigate through a find_all() beautiful soup object?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

If I have the line:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup('A LOT OF HTML HERE', 'html.parser')
all_posts = soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'post'})
```

Is there an equivalent to this pesudocode:

```
for post in all_posts:
    user = post.find('a',{'class':'user123'})
    content = post.find('span',{'class':'content123'})`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens? Have you looked for tutorials / examples? Did they help?

Comment: I believe that your example pseudocode, is working correctly. So what is the question?

Comment: it ends up that i was treating all_posts as an object rather than a list. thanks!